# Failed to activate extension coc-snippets

Tags: vim, neovim

Setting up vim for ts.
Installed plugin
**Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}**

Added extensions
let g:coc_global_extensions = [
\ 'coc-snippets',
\ 'coc-pairs',
\ 'coc-tsserver',
\ 'coc-eslint',
\ 'coc-prettier',
\ 'coc-json',
\ ]

But when editor is open, the following error displays. any help

Using windows 10 OS

[coc.nvim] Error on activate extension coc-snippets: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'H:\c\Users\Administrator.config\coc\ultisnips'

Comment: https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues/2563#issuecomment-757329694

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have installed coc-snippets by executing the following command in your vim/nvim:
   :CocInstall coc-snippets
2. Create a directory in terminal: mkdir 'H:\c\Users\Administrator.config\coc\ultisnips'